# Laravel Auth class does not validate the account

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have saved the user's registration in Laravel 4 with the following code (is OK):

```
$validations = Validator::make($Data, $required);
     // print_r($_POST);

      if($validations->passes())
      {
          $user = new User();
          $user->username = $Data['username'];
          $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
          $user->content = "this is info";
          $user->email = 'mostafatalebi@rocketmail.com';
          $user->save();
           echo "thanks it is been validates";     
       } else { return Redirect::route("register_view")->withErrors($validations); }
```

**But** when I want to authenticate the user with Auth it return false. Here is the code to authenticate the user using the Laravel native Auth Class.

```
$Data = array(
           "password" => Input::get('password'),
           "username" => Input::get('username')
       );
        print_r($Data);
        echo "<br />".Hash::make($Data['password'])."<br />";
        if(Auth::attemp($Data))
        {
         echo "thanks";   
        } 
        else { echo "Problem in Login"; }
```

What do you think is the problem ? thanks

Comment: Did you just misspell `Auth::attempt` in this snippet or is the same error in spelling in your code too? You're missing the last character in this snippet.

Comment: oww what stupid mistake.. thanks yet it was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mispelled `Auth:attempt` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user->password = Hash::make($Data['password']);
```

Tip: Hash the password before passing it.